# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence with np.vstack

Tags: python, numpy

This is my array

Kitchen features

```
[array([228., 232., 230., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.]), array([1.09000000e+02, 1.17000000e+02, 1.45000000e+02, ...,
       1.45868855e-02, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]), array([9.70000000e+01, 9.90000000e+01, 1.03000000e+02, ...,
       5.09565630e-02, 4.56052987e-03, 0.00000000e+00]), array([2.12000000e+02, 2.02000000e+02, 2.05000000e+02, ...,
       2.61085165e-02, 3.02051467e-02, 1.99800693e-02]), array([9.70000000e+01, 1.08000000e+02, 1.12000000e+02, ...,
```

This is the line that is causing the error

> `X = np.vstack((kitchen_features, bathroom_features)).astype(np.float64)`

Is there something I need to do to this array to get it to work?

Comment: That doesn't look like an array to me. That looks like a list of arrays.

Comment: Do I need to change it into just one array to get vstack to work?

Comment: What's the shape and dtype of the arrays that you are trying to combine?

Comment: *********Kitchen features shape  (152412,) First value
*********Kitchen features shape  (123240,) Second value

Comment: It's np.ndarray